# in Liferay 6.2 i have used the Booleanquery that in Liferay 7.0 were deprecated. How i can change this method?

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-7

How can i change this method in liferay 7 ?

```
private static void addVimapFileEntryIdClause(SearchContext searchContext, List<BooleanClause> fieldClauses,long fileEntryIdStart, long fileEntryIdEnd, String vimapFileEntry){

 if (fileEntryIdStart != QueryUtil.ALL_POS) {

    BooleanQuery fileEntryBooleanQuery = BooleanQueryFactoryUtil.create(
                            searchContext);

        if (fileEntryIdStart == fileEntryIdEnd) {

        fileEntryBooleanQuery.addRequiredTerm( 
                   VIMAPConstants.VIMAP_FILE_ENTRY_ID, fileEntryIdStart);
    }
    else {
        fileEntryBooleanQuery.addNumericRangeTerm(
            vimapFileEntry, fileEntryIdStart, fileEntryIdEnd);
        }

    BooleanClause fileEntryFieldClause =
        BooleanClauseFactoryUtil.create(searchContext, 
                  fileEntryBooleanQuery,BooleanClauseOccur.MUST.getName());
            fieldClauses.add(fileEntryFieldClause);
 }
}
```

i change like this but not work good

private static void addFolderIdClause(
            SearchContext searchContext, List> fieldClauses,
            long folderId)
    {
        BooleanQuery folderBooleanQuery = new BooleanQueryImpl();

```
    /*BooleanQuery folderBooleanQuery = BooleanQueryFactoryUtil.create(
                searchContext);*/
    folderBooleanQuery.addRequiredTerm(Field.FOLDER_ID, folderId);

    /*BooleanClause folderFieldClause = BooleanClauseFactoryUtil.create(
                                searchContext, folderBooleanQuery,
                                    BooleanClauseOccur.MUST.getName());*/

    BooleanClause<Query> folderFieldClause =
            BooleanClauseFactoryUtil.create(folderBooleanQuery,
                    BooleanClauseOccur.MUST.getName());

    fieldClauses.add(folderFieldClause);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not `BooleanQuery` that's deprecated, but [`BooleanQueryFactoryUtil`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/search/BooleanQueryFactoryUtil.java). In [there](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/search/BooleanQueryFactoryUtil.java#L20), you can see

```
 * @deprecated As of Wilberforce (7.0.x), , replaced by {@link
 *             com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.generic.BooleanQueryImpl}
```

The (linked) code of the deprecated Util class is quite simple. (note: I've linked to the master branch, not 7.0 - adapt if necessary)